# Combine duplicate rows into one row in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have the following data:
[one person can have multiple Constituency Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48vwN.png)

| Unique_ID | Name | Constituency Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 404 | Mark | Teacher |
| 404 | Mark | Staff |
| 404 | Mark | Staff |
| 659 | Julio | Student |
| 1025 | Jasmine | Staff |
| 1025 | Jasmine | Student |

Question:
Using python and pandas, how would I combine them to this:
[List of unique id and name with all the constituency code combined. Notice that if there are duplicates in constituency code, but it combines it to 1 list of unique constituency code per Unique_ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaKg0.png)

| Unique_ID | Name | Constituency Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 404 | Mark | Teacher, Staff |
| 659 | Julio | Student |
| 1025 | Jasmine | Staff, Student |

I have tried to use groupby and aggregate attributes on pandas, but I am not able to get the result I want. Any suggestions. I know I can do it by iterating through each row, but I rather not do that.

Comment: Please see [how to ask Pandas questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). TL;DR, post formatted text examples of your table and any relevant code you have written.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up data - very important to provide working examples

```
test_data = [
    [404, 'Mark', 'Teacher'],
    [404, 'Mark', 'Staff'],
    [404, 'Mark', 'Staff'],
    [659, 'Julio', 'Student'],
    [1025, 'Jasmine', 'Staff'],
    [1025, 'Jasmine', 'Student']
]
cols = ['Unique_ID', 'Name', 'Constinuency Code']

df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=cols)

df.groupby(['Unique_ID', 'Name'])['Constinuency Code'].apply(lambda grp: list(set(grp))).reset_index()
```

Out

```
   Unique_ID     Name Constinuency Code
0        404     Mark  [Teacher, Staff]
1        659    Julio         [Student]
2       1025  Jasmine  [Student, Staff]
```

If you need a string instead:

```
df.groupby(['Unique_ID', 'Name'])['Constinuency Code'].apply(lambda grp: ', '.join(set(grp))).reset_index()
```

Out

```
   Unique_ID     Name Constinuency Code
0        404     Mark    Teacher, Staff
1        659    Julio           Student
2       1025  Jasmine    Student, Staff
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry new to python, and it was my first time posting here. I did not know about the apply attribute. Thanks a million!

Comment: Of course, no problem. If the answer helped you, you could consider accepting it :)